# Proper way to find the IP address of a website in linux

Tags: kali-linux, ip, nslookup

I am trying to find the IP address of this website [ashesworkshop.org](http://ashesworkshop.org/) using kali linux. I have tried the following commands.

```
dig ashesworkshop.org
```

which returns me an error

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.4-Debian <<>> ashesworkshop.org
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Apart from this, I have tried `nslookup ashesworkshop.org` and `host ashesworkshop.org` which outputs the IP address as `217.160.0.95`. But whenever I enter this IP address on my browser it shows me this error

```
404 Not Found
nginx
```

I am not getting why the IP address is not working. It will be great if someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: The dig error states that you have no access to the configured DNS servers. The Nginx error indicates that there is no page at the root of this web site. I wonder what you mean by "working".

Comment: Why i have no access to that website when I search by IP? whereas I can access it while using the url?

Comment: *"But whenever I enter this IP address on my browser it shows me this error"*.

Some webservers are **not** configured to reply to IP queries. This is specially true for HTTPS web servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
> ```

Your system is not properly configured to look up DNS. Your browser probably still works, because modern browsers bring their own DNS resolvers.

> 404 Not Found

It's neither true that a website is hosted on a single IP address, nor that at a single IP address, there's only one website; at one IP address, arbitrary many domains can be hosted. Also, it's common for large websites to have domains that resolve to different IP addresses, so that load is distributed.

Therefore, a *website in the strict sense doesn't have an IP address*. The *usual* way to interpret HTTP URIs is that the domain part of the address gets resolved to an IP address, but that's not necessarily true for all things you'd consider a website.

Because a single IP address can host multiple domain names, your HTTP client (e.g. browser, curl, wget...) [sends the domain name it "meant"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.4) when it requests a page. When you don't tell your client what domain you mean, it can't do that, and the webserver can't know what page to deliver.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126255/discussion-on-answer-by-marcus-muller-proper-way-to-find-the-ip-address-of-a-web).

Comment: *"and the webserver can't know what page to deliver."* this is gibberish. Web server is a not sentient being. Often both nginx and apache are configured such a way, when there's a request for a web server which is not configured, they use the first configured instance.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thank you very much for the valuable input on the dangers of anthropomorphism when it comes to describing software! You also pointed out that in this case, the webserver is not configured to deliver a default page.